# Writing data to FireBase using Python

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am tring to write data to my firebase project using Python,
I found a code which works for the guy who show it but it does not work for me and I do not understand what the problem is.

This is the code:

```
from firebase import firebase

FBConn = firebase.FirebaseApplication('project-address-here',None)

while True:
    price=int(input("what is the price?"))

    data_to_upload = {
        'Price' : price
    }

    result= FBConn.post('/MyTestData/',data_to_upload)

    print(result)
```

when i run the code i get this message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:/Users/username/Desktop/folder/file.py", line 1, in module
> from firebase import firebase
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\firebase_*init*_.py", line 3
> from .async import process_pool
> ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

What does this mean? how could it be that for him it works and for me it doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem in the firebase module, which is not the *official* one by Google.

The [firebase module from pypy](https://pypi.org/project/firebase/) hasn't been updated for more than 18 months.

Take a look the official SDK documentation at: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#python